# Mongodb terminal command working, not working correctly in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hello i have devised the following query in the terminal for my mongodb database.

```
db.champions.find().sort({wins: -1}).pretty()
```

This correctly outputs in decesnding order according to wins

I have the following code in node js

```
Champion.find().sort({wins: -1}).exec(function (err, ChampionData) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  res.json(ChampionData)
});
```

The response is sent to a controller which outputs the information via angular to a html doc. But it doesn't output in the ordered format i specified (by wins decending)

Can any node js / mongodb guru's please tell me where im going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid question, angular was ordering the results. Sorry!